# Xcode Tab Bar Text Glitch

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, visual-glitch

Recently, I have been trying to add a tab bar to an existing project. However, no matter what I do, the text is being cut off. I am simply trying to drag a Tab Bar Controller into the storyboard and setting it as the initial controller.

This seems to only be an issue in this project, as doing the exact same thing in a test project works fine.

Glitched tab bar

[image]

Glitched tab bar setup in storyboard

[image]

Normal tab bar in test project

[image]

Normal tab bar setup in storyboard

[image]

I am running Xcode v10.3, and the project is already on the App Store. There is no code attached to the VCs, and as far as I am aware, this should not happen.

What are some possible causes or fixes for this?

Comment: Could you show the 2 panels for a tabBarItem: Attributes and Size inspectors.  Otherwise, have you tried the usual "Option-Clean Build Folder" ?

Comment: @claude31 I have already tried cleaning build, closing XCode, turning off and on computer, etc. The first link in the question shows the tab bar item attributes, and https://imgur.com/a/aEJrLpu has the tab bar item size inspector, along with the attribute and size inspector of the tab bar controller.

Comment: You should try do a git diff between the storyboard files, and maybe also the project.pbxproj file, and see if you can spot the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out a cocoapod, AMXFontAutoScale, was to blame. I guess it scales the text of tab bars also.